# Trying to get week number out of date field

Tags: cakephp, date

For a given date field (formatted in sql as: yyyy-mm-dd), I would like to output it as week number.

I tried to work with date() but that didn't really work out.

SQL field: YYYY-MM-DD

Desired output: Week 12 - 2010

Does anyone know how to do this? thanks in advance!!

Comment: What did you try that didn't work out? `date()` does exactly what you want.

Comment: Yup, but somehow (yes i know, i feel stupid) i couldnt get the W-Y right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date`](http://php.net/date) :

```
<?php
$sqldate = "2010/08/28";

echo date("\W\e\e\k W - Y", strtotime($sqldate));
?>
```

Comment: thx! this was so easy i couldn't resist. i forgot to put strtotime() in my own date experiment. thx!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just do it in MySQL, you can use the `WEEK()` function:

```
SELECT WEEK(date) as week, YEAR(date) as year FROM mytable
```

Note, you may want to specify a mode number for `WEEK()` to tell MySQL which day of the week to start on. E.g. some servers may be configured to start weeks on Mondays, whereas other may start on Sundays.

```
SELECT WEEK(date, 0) as week ... /* explicitly start weeks on Sundays */
```

There are also other week number functions for MySQL that you might want to check out, such as `YEARWEEK()`, which returns the year + week number (e.g. 201012):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

Comment: thx for ur answer! the other option was a bit easier though, without changing the sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$bits = explode("-", "2010-08-28");
echo date("W", mktime(0, 0, 0, $bits[1], $bits[2], $bits[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you might try this:

```
echo date("\Week W - Y", date_parse($sql_date_from_db))
```